# Query model for objects that do not have an associated child object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to display summary information about child objects, and about child objects that do and do not contain grandchild objects.  Two of the three work, but not very well.  I am not able to get a result set at all looking for child objects that do contain grandchild objects, though the result for objects that do not contain grandchild objects works.

My models are Campaign, Lead, and leadQA.

Models (relevant)

```py
class Campaign(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)

class Lead(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class LeadQA(models.Model):
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views (relevant)

```py
lead_count_with_qa = list(Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk, leadqa__lead=True).values_list('cid').annotate(Count('id')))
lead_count_without_qa = list(Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk, leadqa=None).values_list('cid').annotate(Count('id')))
lead_qa_count = list(LeadQA.objects.filter(lead__campaign__id=pk).values_list('qa_status').annotate(Count('id')))
```

I get only an empty list for lead_count_with_qa.  I've tried multiple permutations, and there are definitely related leadQA objects that have that object as the foreign key.

Comment: Did you try `Lead.objects.filter(leadqa=None).count()`? For a specific campaign: `Campaign.objects.get(pk=pk).lead_set.filter(leadqa=None)` etc.

Comment: ```lead_count_without_qa = Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk, leadqa=None).count()```
This is so much cleaner and easier to render for what I'm looking for.  What is the inverse for 'lead_count_with_qa'?

Comment: You can use both exclude and filter: `withqa = Leads.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk).exclude(leadqa=None).count()`

Comment: Thank you Haken, solved.

```lead_count_with_qa = Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk).exclude(leadqa=None).count()
lead_count_without_qa = Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk, leadqa=None).count()```
works as intended.

Comment: Cool. The reason I answered in a comment was that I wasn't quite sure if this was what you were trying to do. But since it solved your problem, you can add an answer yourself with the solution. Then you can mark that answer as "accepted". Someone else might find the question useful in the future, and answers are more visible than comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying into .counts() and using .exclude() to find leads that have QA events was what worked best for my use case.

```py
lead_count_with_qa = Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk).exclude(leadqa=None).count()
```

```py
lead_count_without_qa = Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk, leadqa=None).count()
```

Thanks to Håken Lid

Answer (score 0):

For leads with QA:

```
Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk).annotate(qa_count=Count('leadqa')).filter(qa_count__gt=0)
```

For leads without QA:

```
Lead.objects.filter(campaign__id=pk).annotate(qa_count=Count('leadqa')).filter(qa_count=0)
```